# Crear una barra de filtro

Tags: android, android-studio

Por favor quisiera que me dijeran como puedo realizar una barra para filtrar productos. He estado mirando en la app de AliExpress en donde crear este tipo de barra. A continuacion les comparto unas imagenes para que puedan visualizar mejor mi problema.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen de la izquierda, en la parte superior derecha se puede observar un texto llamdo FILTER al darle click se despliega un menu donde se puede seleccionar que filtos desea hacer como el color, el materia, la talla etc.

Quisiera que por favor me ayudaran en darme ideas de como realizar esto. o si existe algun tutorial para poder seguirlo.
Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Bienvenido Delta Dirac, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: De digo los paso basicos que tendrias que hacer para la parte visual y eso, al final te dare unas ideas de como formules las listas de filtros. 1. Crear un proyecto con estilo Navigation Drawer Activity esto para que te aparezca el menu desplegable. 2. Una vez echo esto te vas al app_bar_Activity.xml y alli le arrastras un appBarLayout, el cual te permite agregar las pestañas, dentro de eso tu puedes definir los items que quieres que aparezca como el de la imagen: RESET, FILTER, DONE 3. Crear fragments por cada item, en el fragment para el FILTER puedes insertar todos los objetos que deseas co